# Change webpage live after recieving an input from the user and processing it through python and flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask, frontend

I'm looking to change the page after a user gives an input and clicks submit. I was given the test of making a working luhn algorithm but now I'm struggling with getting the result to display onto the webpage.

Here is the python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from logging.config import dictConfig

dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s: %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'wsgi': {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'stream': 'ext://flask.logging.wsgi_errors_stream',
        'formatter': 'default'
    }},
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'handlers': ['wsgi']
    }
})

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/testcards/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def testcards():
    total = 0
    valid = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cardnum = request.form["cardnum"]
        cardnumarray = list(cardnum)
        app.logger.info(cardnumarray)
        for i in range(0, len(cardnumarray), 1):
            cardnumarray[i] = int(cardnumarray[i])
            pass
        app.logger.info(cardnumarray)
        for x in range(0, len(cardnumarray), 2):
            cardnumarray[x] = cardnumarray[x] * 2
            if cardnumarray[x] >= 10:
                cardnumarray[x] = sum(divmod(cardnumarray[x], 10))
        app.logger.info(cardnumarray)
        for digit in cardnumarray:
            total += cardnumarray[digit]
        app.logger.info(total)
        if total % 10 == 0:
            valid = True
        app.logger.info(valid)
            
    return render_template("testcards.html")
```

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="titlebar">
            <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="MENU"><div class="menubutton"></div></button>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
                <a href="{{ url_for('testcards')}}">Test Cards</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h1>
            Test a card
          </h1>
          <form method="post" id="cardnum">
            <input name="cardnum" placeholder="Input card number to test">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here's my css

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}


.titlebar {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px #000000;
    background-color: lightgrey;
  }
  
.MENU {
    padding-right: 7px;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
  
.menubutton {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transform: scale(var(--ggs,1.2));
    width: 20px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px none;
    
    
    &::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: absolute;
      width: 18px;
      height: 2px;
      background: currentColor;
      border-radius: 3px;
      top: 2px;
      left: 2px;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 0, 0 8px 0
    }
}
  
  .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    width: fit-content;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    border-top-style: none;
}
  
.dropdown-content a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    &:hover {
      background-color: darkgrey;
    }
}

.submit {
  border: none;
}
```

I have tried returning a

tag with a line of python stored inside
`<p>{{print('is card valid? ')+valid}}</p>`

but other than that I haven't been able to think of much else. I'm very new to using flask, I could just redirect the page however I would like for it to update on the same page.

Comment: Typically, templates (e.g. Jinja, Mustache, etc) are used to inject calculated values into an HTML page.